# JS vs C++ expression evaluation

Tags: javascript, c++, expression

I have to rewrite some algorithms from JavaScript to C++. So I have a question: what should I look out for? What differences are between evaluating in JS and C++?

For example, this easing algorithm:

```
var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
var s = period/pi2 * Math.asin(1/amplitude);
if ((t*=2)<1) return -0.5*(amplitude*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1))*Math.sin( (t-s)*pi2/period ));
return amplitude*Math.pow(2,-10*(t-=1))*Math.sin((t-s)*pi2/period)*0.5+1;
```

When I simply change `var`s to `double`s and `Math.` to `std::`, it will compile but `-=` in expression will cause an UB (my compiler says it).

What other tricky differences you know?

Comment: You might want to read about sequence-points, order-of-evaluation and sequencing.

Comment: The question is gigantically broad and unlikely to be answered completely, unless you're expecting us to reprint a few textbooks here.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't think that evaluational sequences in this example are too much different. Undefined behaviour can be caused by subtracting float from integer or by something like that. It also greatly depends on the compiler used and the OS the code is compiled for.

Comment: @VisioN: Seems you should read about those topics for C++ too. And subtraction of float from integer is not a problem.

Comment: @Deduplicator Justify please what you reckon is different in terms of order-of-evaluation in the current example.

Comment: @VisioN: AFAIK, in JS it's completely defined, while in C++ there's only a partial ordering, and there's also UB if you have a write to and a read from the same variable which are unsequenced.

Comment: @VisioN In many places in C++ expressions, there is no order of evaluation (they may be "unsequenced"). In fact, evaluations can be intertwined.

Comment: Yes, in JS it is defined by standard and I was assuming it should be defined in C++ as well, as from what I remember for ANSI C. However you are probably right, as I'm far not an expert in C++.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript and C++ are very uncomparable. It's like apples and oranges. Both are languages which can perform calculations/functions (just like both apples and oranges are fruits), but they share very few similarities.

This is roughly a C++ implementation of your JavaScript code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.141592653589793;
const double twoPI = PI * 2;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    /*
     * I do not know what t is supposed to be, so I
     * randomly chose a value.
     */
    double t = 0.43;

    double amplitude = 1.0;
    double period = 2.0;
    /* I have filled in some standard values for period
       and amplitude because your code did not supply any. */

    double s = (period/twoPI) * asin(1/amplitude);

    if( (t*2) < 1){
        double exponentForPow = 10.0*(t-1);
        double powPiece = amplitude * pow(2.0, exponentForPow);
        double sinPiece = sin(((t-s) * (twoPI/period)));
        double finalAnswer = (-0.5 * powPiece * sinPiece);
        cout << finalAnswer << endl;
    }else{
        double exponentForPow = -10.0*(t-1);
        double powPiece = amplitude * pow(2, exponentForPow);
        double sinPiece = sin(((t-s) * (twoPI/period)));
        double finalAnswer = 1.0 + (0.5*( powPiece * sinPiece ));
        cout << finalAnswer << endl;
    }

    return 0;
    // in C++, the main() function must an integer.
    // You could return finalAnswer if you wrote a
    // second function just for the calculation
}
```

I have not tested this code, so I do not know if it will compile properly or if it will produce the desired result. However, it should give you a good overview or at least a good idea of how the code you posted would be written in C++.

Comment: I'm not a beginner in c++. C++ has expression syntax very similar to JS but quite different semantics. Much JS arithmetic expressions are valid (compilable) C++ expressions. And I'm asking about differences beetwen only expression semantics in these languages, not whole language comparision.

Comment: E.g. expressions that are valid in both languages but will produce different results.